# Spreadsheet design

Tags: excel, vba

I'm designing a file which will calculate a set of certain numbers for each account. Each account has at the moment 5,000 buckets (rows) and 20 selectable criteria (columns). I the future both will grow. I have now 70 accounts, hence use 70 sheets with identical calculation, but the number of accounts will also increase in the future. 
Now, this design is terrible, i had to go and change the formula in all 70 sheets. Is there  another way of designing the workbook? The rows and columns headings will always be identical for all accounts, but the number of rows and columns may change as well as the number of accounts. I researched the topic and there are lots of guidelines as to how not to design. Well I need a recipe of how to do it. Can someone please advise? PS I can do basic/mid level vba.

Comment: When you want to change numerous sheets at once, you can group them together, then you would only have to change it once. Select the first sheet, then press the "Shift" key and select the last sheet. Your sheets are now grouped and what you do to one sheet will change all of them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, as written your question will most likely be closed very soon because it's very broad and not very clear what exactly your issue is. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to modify your question to receive more help. That said, if you can provide at least, screenshots of your data and describe the issue within that context a little more clearly, you may get more help.

Comment: Sounds like you are using Excel as a database. Why not use a database instead? You could still have a macro-enabled workbook which acts as the database front end.

Comment: You've seen the problem yourself, 70 identical tables is a bad design, even for Excel. You must put all that information in only one, and add a field "Account Name", then, you'll be able to Pivot, Sort, Format, Reformulate ....

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I would recommend writing a macro that would produce the current "template" (ie, column headers and formulas), and running that on any new sheet for new account creation. Then, when the data model changes and you need to change columns/formulas, you can change the template creation macro to match the new model and do a quick:

```
For Each sht in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    CreateTemplate(sht)
Next
```

to change all the existing sheets.

If you structure the sheets so that doing that doesn't mess with your source data, you can keep them all tidy without a lot of work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I do use a macro that checks all the headings. Sorry I realise my question is very vague. This particular design limits me very much in analysing and using the data. I.e I cannot use pivot tables etc. I though someone might share their experience of how to deal with expanding 3d data tables

Comment: Ah. In that case, unfortunately, I would recommend moving out of Excel and into Access. There's several SO questions about how to migrate data from Excel to Access through VBA, or you can use Access's native ability. For what you're describing, I'd put all 350000 ish rows into one table, with a field for "AccountID". Then you can use Access's queries to explore and analyze the data, or create subsets that you can export back to Excel.